# Is "There exists a circle passing through any three noncollinear points" really equivalent to Euclid's parallel postulate?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

This site [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/parallel-postulate.html](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/junkyard/parallel-postulate.html) lists from the book
"The Foundations of Geometry and the Non-Euclidean Plane" by George E. Martin 26 propositions which are suppose to be equivalent to the parallel postulate. In particular Proposition I states:

> There exists a circle passing through any three noncollinear points.

However, I would say this is valid in spherical geometry, so it can't be equivalent to the parallel postulate since the parallel postulate is not valid in spherical geometry.

Answer (score 11):

As the linked site says, these are equivalents to the parallel postulate *within absolute geometry*.  Spherical geometry is not a model of absolute geometry, so this equivalence does not apply in that context.

(Absolute geometry is roughly "Euclidean geometry without assuming the parallel postulate", but the parallel postulate is not the only part of Euclidean geometry that fails in spherical geometry.  There are different ways to precisely define "absolute geometry" which are not all exactly equivalent (and I'm not sure which one Martin's book uses), but roughly it means you are in either Euclidean geometry or hyperbolic geometry.)

Comment: Thanks, but if 'absolute geometry is roughly "Euclidean Geometry without assuming the parallel postulate"' why does he include it in absolute geometry?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What is "it"?

Comment: the parallel postulate.

Comment: The parallel postulate is not included as an axiom in absolute geometry.  I'm not sure where you got the impression that it is included.

Comment: The link says the parallel postulate can exist "within  absolute geometry".

Comment: The parallel postulate *can* be true in a model of absolute geometry, but it doesn't *have* to be true.  Absolute geometry neither proves nor disproves the parallel postulate.

Comment: Is there a proof that the parallel postulate has to be false?

Comment: No, not in absolute geometry.

Comment: One can prove the existence of at least one parallel line from the other axioms. Some authors call the union of Euclidean and hyperbolic neutral geometry, and absolute geometry the union of Euclidean, hyperbolic and spherical geometry. The result cited above is valid in neutral geometry. In neutral geometry parallel lines exist.

Comment: The main reason why I posted this question, was because I have been exploring the possibility of using circles to prove the parallel postulate from within Euclidean geometry. I wanted to make sure that by using circles I was not relying on a proposition that is fully equivalent to the parallel postulate to prove the parallel postulate.

Comment: I also think the proposition: 
_There exists a circle passing through any three noncollinear points_
is valid in hyperbolic geometry

Comment: The webpage https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/pythpar/Fifth.shtml states that the proposition _There exists a circle passing through any three noncollinear points_ is equivalent to the parallel postulate but makes no mention of absolute or neutral geomerty. I guess this is an inaccurate statement of equivalency.

Comment: @EuclidLookedOnBeautyBare "I also think the proposition: There exists a circle passing through any three noncollinear points is valid in hyperbolic geometry" - this is actually false. I suggest using a model to find a counter-example to this belief.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I will take your word for it. Circles do exist  for some sets of three noncollinear points in hyperbolic geometry?

Comment: @EuclidLookedOnBeautyBare: Of course they do. However, I suggest not taking my word  for it but working out a proof. Keep in mind that every Euclidean circle contained in the upper half plane is also a hyperbolic circle (just with a different center) and vice versa. As for an example, I suggest taking the points $i, i-1, i+1$ in the upper half plane model. Prove that they do not belong to a common hyperbolic circle and also do not belong to a common hyperbolic line.

Comment: If you want the machine checked proof of this theorem: https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01178236v1

Comment: @JulienNarboux so it has been proven that the truth of the parrallel postulate cannot be decided from within Euclidean geometry?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I got a sense of what is possible by imagining a hyperbolic (saddle) surface and using geodesic construction to find the centre of the circle from three points.  Unlike spherical geometry the geodesics corresponding to the radius of the circle will not necessarily be of equal length.

Comment: @JulienNarboux, Arthur Schopenhauer thought the attempts to prove the parallel postulate were foolish and unnecessary, not because he thought the postulate was false or just a useful fiction, but because he considered it to be a true perception of the mind.   However, even if the parallel postulate is fundamentally true, it does not necessarily invalidate the utility of non-euclidean geometries if it can be shown they make use of the parallel postulate in some indirect or implicit way.